# How to upload binary data to Amazon S3 from a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3

I am using the gems [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) & [aws-s3](https://github.com/dsboulder/aws-s3) to upload images to Amazon S3 from my Rails app. This all works fine. What I am now trying to do is upload some binary data to S3 and return the URL. How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by binary data? Aren't images binary data too? What are you exactly trying to do that does not work?

Answer (score 1):

You'll find a tutorial with examples here:

http://amazon.rubyforge.org

Look at the S3Object.store method.

EDIT:

You should now use the official Amazon SDK:

http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/